# FolderBrowserDialog not found - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

The title states it all, I even tried adding `using System.Windows.Forms` but it still tells me that `FolderBrowserDialog` is not found.

Anything I can do? Any other way I can browse for directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

You can see this in the documentation for [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Forms
>
> Assembly:  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

The namespace is what you add via `using`, the assembly is what needs to be referenced.

Comment: and marked as answer!